# Unable to pass session explicitly within different functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script in python using requests module and BeautifulSoup library to scrape the title of different posts from their inner pages traversing multiple pages using next page button. To be clearer - the script parses the links from such [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?tab=newest&page=606&pagesize=50) and scrape the title from such [inner page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500016/html-agility-pack-screen-scraping-xpath-isnt-returning-data).

I've created session once within main function and reuse the same without passing it in different functions (I don't know if this is an ideal way).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?tab=newest&page=604&pagesize=50"
base = "https://stackoverflow.com"

def get_links(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        yield urljoin(base,item.get("href"))

    next_page = soup.select_one("a[rel='next']")
    if next_page:
        next_page = urljoin(base,next_page.get("href"))
        yield from get_links(next_page)

def fetch_info(link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    title = soup.select_one("h1 > a.question-hyperlink").text
    return title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'
        for item in get_links(link):
            print(fetch_info(item))
```

> ***How can I pass session explicitly within different functions keeping the existing design as is?***

Comment: One option would be to wrap the function's inside a class, initialize the session in ``__init__``  assign to ``self`` and access it.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I don't wanna go for class. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `global` which is a **very** bad coding practice or you use classes which is what you should be doing.

Comment: You're already using `s` in different functions, what exactly are you trying to achieve here and why can't you use classes?

Comment: I would like to pass the session as parameter in different functions other than the way I've used @Lucan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code relies on Python scoping rules. In your functions, it searches the name `s`

- in local scope, and fails then
- <s>in enclosing function, which is not the case for your code</s>
- in global scope and succeeds
- <s>in builtin names</s>

Since you don't have any other session, I think it is okay to be implicit in your case.

> How can I pass session explicitly within different functions **keeping the existing design** as is?

The closest one you can get is this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?tab=newest&page=604&pagesize=50"
base = "https://stackoverflow.com"


def get_links(s, url):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".summary .question-hyperlink"):
        yield urljoin(base, item.get("href"))

    next_page = soup.select_one("a[rel='next']")
    if next_page:
        next_page = urljoin(base, next_page.get("href"))
        yield from get_links(s, next_page)


def fetch_info(s, link):
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    title = soup.select_one("h1 > a.question-hyperlink").text
    return title


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36'
        for item in get_links(s, link):
            print(fetch_info(s, item))
```

Comment: I also thought of this but wasn't sure. Thanks @Asocia.